# Android Device reboots as soon as it goes in suspend state

Tags: android, linux, power-management, acpi

I'm porting Android Lollipop on x86_64, seeing one weird behavior from device.

As soon as device goes in suspend state it reboots the device.

Please help me to investigate the reason behind it, what all the possible methods to reboot the device without using power button (i.e. from kernel code, android framework).

After lot of research, what all I can conclude is, that this issue was caused by unsupported sleep state provided by ACPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting automatically can be down (but not limited) to a few different things:

1. **WiFi** related
2. **Lock screen** related
3. **Storage related** - Some users report that a low internal storage was the cause of this, and simply freeing up some space fixed this
4. **Battery related** - Malfunctioning or insufficiently charged battery
5. **Power button** related - Many report that dirty can get stuck under the power button, triggering the button randomly. Pressing it in hard can remedy this

On top of these known reasons, it seems that this is a recognised problem with the Lollipop update.

User Nitin Dhage from the following [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/nexus/X6ZjAAauATc/z7Q0Up-BjCAJ) page wrote:

> I'm also facing the same issue (restart when phone locks, red.)
>   however if I set the other security type except pattern the problem is
>   solved. If we use PIN or NONE then the problem will solve, the problem
>   is with Pattern security type only.

You may want to join the following discussion regarding the topic of **Restarting frequently from lock screen after updating to Lollipop**

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/nexus/X6ZjAAauATc/MmPqyAay3UMJ

Comment: Thanks Smittey,
I tried by disabling WIFi, and investigated for Lock Screen, and Power Button and it seems that's not the cause of reboot.

On my device I'm seeing, kernel panics when device goes in sleep/suspend and tried to disabled panics causing reboot but no help.

Only clue so far I have is, "It's taking ~15 secs to reboot after going in suspend mode if I'm not touching the hardware otherwise it reboots as soon as it goes in suspend state."